# Automated Unit Testing - SPFX Application Customiser

Tags: automated-tests, jestjs, office365, sharepoint-online

I am trying to implement automated unit test cases using jest for SPFX Application customizer. But currently i could not find out any solution to mock the SPFX methods. Is there any way by which i can mock SharePoint context or the methods which return required properties.